# Count how many suggests are in textbox in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, textbox, dataset

I'm using this code for suggest names as I write on textbox.
When there's no more suggest, I'd like to show a new form but I don't know how to count suggested itens.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

```
    If txt_nome.Text.Length >= 3 Then

        Using con As NpgsqlConnection = GetConnection()

            Dim sql As String
            sql = "SELECT nome FROM dados_pessoais"
            Dim cmd As NpgsqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand(sql, con)
            Dim da As NpgsqlDataAdapter = New NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim ds As New DataSet

            da.Fill(ds, "list")
            Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                col.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("nome").ToString())
            Next
            txt_nome.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            txt_nome.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
            txt_nome.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest

        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count` will get you what you need...

Answer (score -1):

Could you please try this

1. Add this on you public class form (above the name of your form)

`Dim c As New NsqlConnection(GetConnection)`

`Dim cmd As New NsqlCommand`

`Dim da As New NsqlDataAdapter`

`Dim dr As NsqlDataReader`

`Dim ds, ds1 As New DataSet`

then paste this anywhere inside public class

```
Sub CountNumbers
Dim x as integer
Try
ds.Clear()
c.Open()
cmd = New NsqlCommand("SELECT Count(nome) FROM dados_pessoais", c)
da = New NsqlDataAdapter(cmd)
da.Fill(ds, "dados_pessoais")
x = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)
if x = 0 then
'Go to your Form
else
'Do Nothing
end if

Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
c.Close()
End Try


End Sub
```

the in your code above write this

`CountNumbers`

above the end sub

I write this without trying if this one work but if not i will assist you on your error. this is the long method but im sure there is a short one